# How are two different inherited pointer addresses equal?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

After reading [C++: Comparing pointers of base and derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662719/c-comparing-pointers-of-base-and-derived-classes), I thought for sure this wouldn't work.

When I executed this, the printed addresses for `c_as_b` and `&c` were different, so why does this print "seems safe to compare pointers in same hierarchy"?  What is being compared besides the printed addresses that could result in true?

Can you give a similar small example where the `==` results in false?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A { std::string s; };
struct B { int i; };
struct C : A, B { double d; };

int main() {
    C c;
    B* c_as_b = &c;
    A* c_as_a = &c;
    cout << "c_as_a: " << c_as_a << endl
         << "c_as_b: " << c_as_b << endl
         << "&c:     " << &c << endl;
    cout << (c_as_b == &c ? "seems safe to compare pointers in same hierarchy" : "definately not safe") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
c_as_a: 0xbfb98f10
c_as_b: 0xbfb98f14
&c:     0xbfb98f10
seems safe to compare pointers in same hierarchy
```

Comment: I don't know the standard on this, but looks like there might be an implicit dynamic_cast on `&c` to convert it to `B*` before comparing

Comment: dynamic_cast can be expensive, and is never implicitly done

Comment: "*What is being compared besides the printed addresses that could result in true?*" The two pointers after being statically cast to the common type.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x, there can be no dynamic cast here, there are no virtual functions.

Comment: right, I always mix up my terminology for conversions/casts

Comment: A way the comparison would result in false: `static_cast<void*>(c_as_b) == static_cast<void*>(&c)`

Comment: Where did you get the notion that a dynamic cast is expensive?

Comment: @EdHeal Well, it's expensive compared to other types of casts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pointer equality comparison `c_as_b == &c` will do an implicit pointer conversion. From [expr.eq]:

> If at least one of the operands is a pointer, pointer conversions (4.10), function pointer conversions (4.12),
>   and qualification conversions (4.4) are performed on both operands to bring them to their composite pointer
>   type (Clause 5).

Basically, `&c` will be converted to a `B*` so that the comparison can happen. At which point, it is exactly the same as `c_as_b` (since that's how you got that pointer to begin with), so they compare equal.

Comment: What is "[expr.eq]"?

Comment: @JDiMatteo It's a section heading in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, `c` is statically upcast to B, and then compared with `c_as_b` yielding true.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the part of the question that nobody touched on: **Can you give a similar small example where the == results in false?**

Here is a similar example where the `==` results in false, using `dynamic_cast<void*>` makes the same comparison true, and commented out is a way that `==` results in a compile time error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A { virtual ~A() {} };
struct B : A { };
struct C : A { };
struct D : B, C { };

int main() {
    D d;
    C* c = &d;
    B* b = &d;
    A* a_through_b = b; // &d results in error: 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'D'
    A* a_through_c = c;
    cout << "&d:           " << &d << endl
         << "c :           " << c << endl
         << "b :           " << b << endl
         << "a_through_b : " << a_through_b << endl
         << "a_through_c : " << a_through_c << endl;
    cout << (a_through_b == a_through_c ? "a_through_b == a_through_c" : "a_through_b != a_through_c") << endl;
    cout << (dynamic_cast<void*>(a_through_b) == dynamic_cast<void*>(a_through_c) ? "dynamic_cast<void*>(a_through_b) == dynamic_cast<void*>(a_through_c)" : "dynamic_cast<void*>(a_through_b) != dynamic_cast<void*>(a_through_c)") << endl;
    //cout << (a_through_c == &d) << endl; // error: 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'D'
    cout << (dynamic_cast<void*>(a_through_c) == dynamic_cast<void*>(&d) ? "dynamic_cast<void*>(a_through_c) == dynamic_cast<void*>(&d)" : "dynamic_cast<void*>(a_through_c) != dynamic_cast<void*>(&d)") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
&d:           0xbff6d558
c :           0xbff6d55c
b :           0xbff6d558
a_through_b : 0xbff6d558
a_through_c : 0xbff6d55c
a_through_b != a_through_c
dynamic_cast<void*>(a_through_b) == dynamic_cast<void*>(a_through_c)
dynamic_cast<void*>(a_through_c) == dynamic_cast<void*>(&d)
```